# session list is not updated after the from is submitted in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

# Create your views here.
class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label="New Task")
    

def index(request):
    if "tasks" not in request.session:
        request.session["tasks"] = []
    return render(request,"tasks/index.html",{
        "tasks":request.session["tasks"]
    })
    

def add(request):
    if request.method ==  "POST":
        form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newtask = form.cleaned_data["task"]
            request.session["tasks"] += [newtask]
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request,"tasks/add.html",{
        "form" : form
    })
        
        
    return render(request,"tasks/add.html",{
        "form" : NewTaskForm()
    })
```

When ever I try to submit a new value, everything go well and it redirected me to the index.html but my list is not updated and I don't know why, because of this nothing is rendering when I get redirected to the index.html

```
{% for task in tasks %}
     <li>{{task}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

should submit my from to add.html not index.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).